# Lazy Loading of Richfaces CollapsiblePanel

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces, java-ee-6

I'm working with Richfaces 4 and want to use the rich:collapsiblePanel to display a table (tab2) inside anothers table (tab1) row.

Due I'm working with large datasets I hoped that the EJB Methods to fill the rows in tab2 are only called if the panel is expanded. Its right, the "tab2" is not rendered in the DOM if the panel is closed, but EJB Methods to fill tab2 are called.

Is this still a bug in Richfaces4 or am I using the collapsiblePanel in a wrong way.

```
<rich:dataTable id="tab1" value="#{controller.tab1.wrappedData}" var="row">
  <rich:column ....>

    <rich:collapsiblePanel header="tabs" expanded="false" switchType="ajax" rendered="#{row.someBool}">
      <rich:dataTable value="#{controller2.getValues(row.id)}" var="tab2row">
        <rich:column>

          <h:outputText value="#{tab2row.name}" />

        </rich:column>
      </rich:dataTable>
    </rich:collapsiblePanel>
  </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

My problem is, that the getters of the outputText are called if the page is initially rendered and all panels are closed.